# Processing heavy operations with doGet() method on a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

The tool I'm working on can only send GET requests, and I need to process heavy operations using the information contained within the request. These operations then return a String containing a URL I will use for redirection.

After doing some researches, I've found that doGet() method is rather used for pre-processing a request, while doPost() can be used for post-processing.

Is there any way I can do these heavy operations using the doGet() method ? If I have to use the doPost() method, how can I "turn" my request into a POST request ?

Thanks.

Edit : I've already tried to process these heavy operations within the doGet method. But it seems the servlet doesn't wait until the url String I use for redirection is generated. I've read it's a bad thing to try to synchronize your doGet() method performance-wise.

Edit 2 - About what I'm trying to do : The tool I'm working on is an Oracle solution. You can launch custom actions within the client, including web applications. Launching a custom action will send a GET request to the application, containing all the information about the page from which you launched the application (user, item selected, etc) and the application then uses this information to process the heavy operations I talked about. Operations consist of creating a new session on the Oracle client using the same IDs, making queries based on the item selected, creating XML Data and even using an external program located on the Oracle server. Finally, it returns a download URL from where you can download a PDF report, and I use this URL to redirect the application.

Here's the servlet code :

```
package com.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.actions.agileSessionHandler;
import com.actions.BOMComparisonReport;

public class DefaultServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException{

        agileSessionHandler handler = new agileSessionHandler(...);
        BOMComparisonReport report = new BOMComparisonReport(...);
        handler.setSessionObject(request);
        String url = report.generateBOMReport(...);
        request.setAttribute("redirectURL", url);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/BOMCompDefault.jsp" ).forward( request, response );
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this in the literature? I wouldn't characterize the difference between those two methods as pre- and post-processing. Are you perhaps misunderstanding how **idempotent** HTTP methods work?

Comment: Show us the Servlet code .

Answer (score 1):

> *I've already tried to process these heavy operations within the doGet method. But it seems the servlet doesn't wait until the url String I use for redirection is generated*

It sounds like as if you're firing a new thread and completely forgetting it. This is a very bad idea in a Java EE environment. Don't do that. Just do the processing in the very same thread (i.e. do not create a `new Thread()` at all). If you really intend to do it asynchronously, then you should be using e.g. `@Asynchronous` method on an EJB and then make use of polling or pushing to inform the client about the progress/results.

It doesn't matter whether you do it in a GET or POST request. The point is, GET requests are idempotent, bookmarkable, re-executable with exactly the same result everytime. Think of a SQL `SELECT` query. POST requests aren't. They are to be used to manipulate data in the server end. Think of performing a SQL `UPDATE` or `DELETE` query. You don't want that your data get modified or deleted on every F5 press or even when a searchbot comes along indexing the GET links, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "turn" the request into a `POST` request, You can simply call the `doPost` method from `doGet` but that won't change anything if you want the `POST` functionality.

If your tool is sending large number of request parameters, then all the parameters will be appended in the url which is not safe at all.

In case of `GET` request, the length of the url that can be managed succesfully also differs container to container.

As told by The New Idiot, **idempotency means performing the same operation over and over again without causing any side effects**.

The method `GET` is idempotent as it just asks for the resource and requesting a resource over and over again cannot cause any problem but `POST` consists of form submission and entering the form data more than once can cause serious problems. 
    **Try considering the example when your money transaction happens more than one time for single onlien purchase**.

Simple links for the resources are `GET` requests, you can bookmark them and request over and over again.

GET requests are less secure because all the parameters are visible in the url, while `POST` requests are more secure as they are not shown anywhere in the url.

Most of the times, `GET` url can be 2048 characters, that means you can send limited data.
  In case of `POST` method, there is no limit for the data to be sent

Comment: I thought about this solution, but it's highly deprecated according to what I've read.

Comment: @TomG I understand that, thats why I have edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no classification of `POST` and `GET` methods on the basis of *heavy operations* .`GET` is idempotent whereas `POST` is not. GET is idempotent meaning thereby that the same operation applied multiple times should yield the same result, where as with a POST it has side effects.

GET as the name suggests is used to get something back from the server , whereas POST should be used to post data to the server for further processing . Though , nobody can stop you from implementing a non-idempotent GET method.

According to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) :

> **GET** requests a representation of the specified resource. Note that GET should not be used for operations that cause side-effects, such as using it for taking actions in web applications. One reason for this is that GET may be used arbitrarily by robots or crawlers, which should not need to consider the side effects that a request should cause.
>
> **POST** submits data to be processed (e.g., from an HTML form) to the identified resource. The data is included in the body of the request. This may result in the creation of a new resource or the updates of existing resources or both.

With GET you can *post* limited data to the server using the query string and again they are limited as URLs cannot be of infinite length . Also the data shows up in the browser window.

> I've read it's a bad thing to try to synchronize your doGet() method performance-wise.

What are you trying to do ? Each request will have its own thread executing the `doGet()` method .